# Express.js Benefits to using Router vs App.use routing?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

According to [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html), both `app.use` and Router implement the router interface and can both serve as middleware.

So basically you can define routes by doing

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
```

or you can also do

```
var router = express.Router();
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  next();
})
app.use(router);
```

I was just wondering if there is a reason I would use a router over the app? The only thing I can find on using one or the other is that I need to be consistent with my `params`. Just curious.

Comment: It is useful when nesting routes and keeping code organized in separate files. Generate an application with the [express generator](https://github.com/expressjs/generator) to see a basic example of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using routes can help organize your code in Express/Node.

This is how I'm using it when I have a specific post request in JSON, but not all requests coming in will be JSON, so I have to parse the JSON only in this instance and subsequently respond:

Using an app on its own:

```
    app.use("/search", bodyParser.json());
    app.post("/search", function(request, response) {
        params= request.body;
        getSearchResults(params.words, params.numbers, response);
    });
```

Using an app with a specific router:

```
    var jsonPostRouter= express.Router();
    jsonPostRouter.use(bodyParser.json())
    jsonPostRouter.use( function(request, response) {
        var params= request.body;
        getSearchResults(params.words, params.numbers, response);
    });

    app.use("/search", jsonPostRouter);
```

I can then put the router code in a separate module and simply have the `app.use("/search", jsonPostRouter);` in my main server code, which helps keep my code organized and easier to follow.

Comment: Oh I see thanks a lot. Great example by the way. I can see how this will scale a lot better too. Appreciate it :)

Comment: So the same can be accomplished if you change the line to `var jsonPostRouter= express()`

What is the benefit of using express.Router() vs. mounting an app? I imagine it just creates slightly less overhead, but is it even noticeable?